# ifetex always true

Tags: xetex, e-tex

I am working on a document preamble that allows me to compile a document with `pdlatex` and with `xelatex`. I found that the `\ifetex` condition to check whether the document is going through e-tex is always true, independent of the engine that I use.

Below is a minimal example. The `eTeX used ...` part is in all result documents independent of the engine that I use: `pdflatex`, x`elatex`, and `latex`. The "PDF used..." part is only in the document that ran through `pdflatex`.

Any ideas? 
Is there a general mistake in my thoughts?

The documentation of `\ifetex` says it simply tests for the `\eTeXversion`. Who sets this?

I am on a Fedora 19 installation and also tried it on a Fedora 20 without the etex stuff installed at all -- same behavior. Can somebody test this at a different installation, i.e., whether the behavior is the same?

Is there a 'best-practice' to do the engine selection in a document preamble if I want (need) to be able to run the document through any of the major engines? So I mean to construct a if(pdf)-elsif(etex)-elsif(latex)-fi chain.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{ifetex}

\begin{document}

Hello World

\ifpdf
    PDF used
\fi

\ifetex
    eTeX used; version is \the\eTeXversion \the\eTeXversion
\fi

\end{document}
```

Comment: You seem to confuse etex and xetex. etex (expanded tex commands) is used by all current engines.

Comment: Great! ... so simple :-) That's it ... Thanks!

Comment: Note also that `ifpdf` checks if PDFTeX is run in PDF mode, not whether the engine is PDFTeX or not and it will return true for LuaTeX as well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The e-TeX extensions were finalised in 1999 and are available in the common engines: pdfTeX, LuaTeX and XeTeX. With a recent-ish TeX system (say anything released in the last 5-8 years), the extensions are enabled in the LaTeX format files as standard. The only 'common' case where the extensions are not enabled is when using 'classical' TeX:

```
tex <filename>
```

as they are not part of Knuth's original design and `tex` always invokes that.

It is quite possible to build a format without the extensions, or to run across an older TeX system which either requires they be asked for explicitly (`elatex`, *etc.*) or doesn't have them at all (some proprietary systems, for example).

The extensions themselves are still maintained as a patch against Knuth's TeX, so they have a version independent of the engine (pdfTeX, *etc.*) in use. All of the systems which enable the e-TeX primitives include the version string for the e-TeX extensions. Thus this primitive is a good test for the extensions being available. (Note: with LuaTeX it is possible to enable the extensions without `\eTeXversion`, but extremely unlikely in practice and is not really worth worrying about.)

Comment: Actually the LuaTeX situation is a little more complex as it doesn't provide `\TeXXeTstate` and other e-TeX bidirectional primitives (it uses a different model). However, if this is an issue a specific LuaTeX test is also available.

Comment: Josehp, thanks for the explanation. As Ulrike pointed out, my mistake was to be confused about e-TeX and XeLaTex.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, the solution is simple.

```
\usepackage{ifetex} -> \usepackage{if**x**etex}

\ifetex -> \ifxetex
```

Sorry for the confusion :-)